# CPP Kernel Module

Tags: c++, linux-kernel

Looking at kernel modules, there is a lot of code written in C that pretends to be C++ like (e.g. structs of function pointers, 'constructors', 'destructors' end even #defining keywords like 'nullptr' and even 'new' ).

if kernel modules would be written in C++ a lot of effort could be avoided, and also the code would be more readable and easier to maintain.

What are the technical reasons for not using C++ for kernel modules?

I can name two:

- Exceptions do not work ([see discussion and possible solutions here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-exceptions-the-linux-kernel/229100146)).
- new needs to be re-implemented using kalloc.

What else?

Comment: [This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQSQy-7lveQ&list=PLHTh1InhhwT7J5jl4vAhO1WvGHUUFgUQH&index=85) from CppCon 2016 might be interesting for you.